# Subset dataframe based on large values of a column per month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, grouping, subset

I have a df like that:

| month | stock | MV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-07 | A | 50 |
| 1994-07 | B | 60 |
| 1994-07 | C | 70 |
| 1994-07 | D | 80 |
| 1994-08 | A | 90 |
| 1994-08 | B | 60 |
| 1994-08 | C | 70 |
| 1994-08 | D | 95 |
| 1994-08 | E | 100 |
| 1994-08 | F | 110 |

I would like to subset my df in a way that I only have in it the 50% of the highest MV per month. For July/1994 I only have 4 stock, so 50% will be the 2 highest MV. For the month after, I have 6 stocks, which gives me 3 highest values:

| month | stock | MV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-07 | C | 70 |
| 1994-07 | D | 80 |
| 1994-08 | D | 95 |
| 1994-08 | E | 100 |
| 1994-08 | F | 110 |

I have tried:

`df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).nlargest(2, "MV")`

But I got the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nlargest'
In addition, the value of n will need to be a different value for every month. I am not sure how to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `apply` and compute the final length:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(len(g)//2, 'MV'))
```

with the provided data as string:

```
(df.groupby('month', as_index=False, group_keys=False) # use pd.Grouper if needed here
   .apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(len(g)//2, 'MV'))
   .sort_values(by=['month', 'MV'])
)
```

output:

```
     month stock   MV
2  1994-07     C   70
3  1994-07     D   80
7  1994-08     D   95
8  1994-08     E  100
9  1994-08     F  110
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.groupby('month').apply(lambda monthly_data: monthly_data[monthly_data['MV'] >= monthly_data['MV'].median())`

Answer (score 2):

You can sorting values and then select 50% of length of values in lambda function:

```
df = (df.sort_values(['month','MV'])
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"), group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x)) // 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `apply`

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(2, "MV"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `median` (or `quantile`):

```
out = df.loc[df['MV'] > df.groupby('month')['MV'].transform('median')]
print(out)

# Output
     month stock   MV
2  1994-07     C   70
3  1994-07     D   80
7  1994-08     D   95
8  1994-08     E  100
9  1994-08     F  110
```

Same version with `quantile` but you have more control if you want to change the percentage:

```
out = df.loc[df['MV'] > df.groupby('month')['MV'].transform('quantile', 0.5)]
print(out)

# Output
     month stock   MV
2  1994-07     C   70
3  1994-07     D   80
7  1994-08     D   95
8  1994-08     E  100
9  1994-08     F  110
```